# Highcharts | Network Graph - Is there a way to expand leaf nodes on click of the Parent node?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Highcharts | Network Graph - Is there a way to expand leaf nodes on click of the Parent node?

[image]

[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/preethis01/zd7cb3tk/14/)`Highcharts.addEvent(
Highcharts.Series,
'afterSetOptions',
function (e) {
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().color
i = 0,
nodes = {};

```
    if (
        this instanceof Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph &&
        e.options.id === 'lang-tree'
    ) {
        e.options.data.forEach(function (link) {

            if (link[0] === 'Parent') {
                nodes['Parent'] = {
                    id: 'Parent',
                    marker: {
                        radius: 20
                    }
                };
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1],
                    marker: {
                        radius: 10
                    },
                    color: colors[i++]
                };
            } else if (nodes[link[0]] && nodes[link[0]].color) {
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1],
                    color: nodes[link[0]].color
                };
            }
        });

        e.options.nodes = Object.keys(nodes).map(function (id) {
            return nodes[id];
        });
    }
}
```

);`

Answer (score 4):

Currently, this feature is not available to achieve from the API options without any customization.

Please take a look at this demo where you can find some custom functions to collapse the child nodes on the `click` event: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9mv0ny3j/

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      var point = this;
      point.linksFrom.forEach(link => {
        if (link.toNode.isHidden) {
            link.graphic.show();
          link.toNode.graphic.css({
            opacity: 1
          });
          link.toNode.dataLabel.css({
            opacity: 1
          })
          link.toNode.isHidden = false;
        } else {
          link.graphic.hide();
          link.toNode.graphic.css({
            opacity: 0
          });
          link.toNode.dataLabel.css({
            opacity: 0
          })
          link.toNode.isHidden = true;
        }
      })
    }
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.click

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I just carried on with some customizations.